# How to download a file from one byte to another byte.(for example downloading footer of an html file)

Tags: python, download

How can I download a file from one byte to another byte.(for example downloading footer of an html file) with python3??

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by “byte” here?

Comment: Well,I mean for example divide a file's size to 10 parts and download one part of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python you could do something like:

```
import urllib2

def read_range(url, rstart, rstop):
    # First request url
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)

    # Ignore content to start byte
    response.read(max(rstart-1,0))

    # Read bytes we want.
    return response.read(rstop - rstart)

# First 200 bytes.
print read_range("http://stackoverflow.com", 0, 200)

# Last 200 bytes
print read_range("http://stackoverflow.com", 200, 0)

# Some bytes right in the middle
print read_range("http://stackoverflow.com", 400, 1000)

# Read whole file
print read_range("http://stackoverflow.com", 0, -1)
```

This will of course send a 200-request without any special headers, but still does what you ask for.

Answer (score 0):

If the server sends back an `Accept-Ranges: bytes` header, it means you can request specific ranges by setting the `Range` header, as in `Range: bytes=1170-1246` here:

```
~: curl -v http://example.com/ -r 1170-1246
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 93.184.216.119...
* Connected to example.com (93.184.216.119) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Range: bytes=1170-1246
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.0
> Host: example.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Cache-Control: max-age=604800
< Content-Range: bytes 1170-1246/1270
< Content-Type: text/html
< Date: Tue, 03 Jun 2014 16:37:10 GMT
< Etag: "359670651"
< Expires: Tue, 10 Jun 2014 16:37:10 GMT
< Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT
< Server: ECS (sea/F622)
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< 
<p><a href="http://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
```

If not, you’ll just have to request the entire the page and use the usual Python slice.

You can send the `Range` header without checking for `Accept-Ranges` first; just make sure to differentiate between a 200 and 206 response.

This only works if you know exactly which bytes you want.

Comment: Worth mentioning that following quote from curl man-pages: `You should also be aware that many HTTP/1.1 servers do not have this feature enabled, so that when you attempt to get a range, you'll instead get the whole document.`